# Doctype correct?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, doctype

I'm trying to do and exemple of this site: http://www.compilr.org/struts-2-and-hibernate-4-application/1343/

But when i execute the aplicacion I can see this error on the Eclipse console: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found

But the code I think that is correct, is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<mapping resource="entity/Login.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
```

Could any give me a hand?

Thanks from Barcelona - Spain